# How to use an IP quintuple as a key of a hash table (using google's dense_hash_map)?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, hash, network-programming

We can use an IP quintuple to identify a network connction: srcIP, srcPort, dstIP, dstPort, TCP/UDP. I want to keep those connection information with a hash table just like this `Hash<quintuple, list<packet_information> >`.

Now I'm using a string to be the hash table's key like "srcIP_srcPort_dstIP_dstPort_TCP/UDP", but I think it's not a good choice because of its efficiency.

So, if I want to use a struct to be the key, maybe like:

```
struct IP_QUINTUPLE
{
    uint32_t srcIP;
    uint16_t srcPort;
    uint32_t dstIP;
    uint16_t dstPort;
    uint8_t  flag;  // 0(tcp)/1(udp)
};
```

How to implement the hash function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any hash function.
For example:

item = IP_QUINTUPLE.

```
hash1 = item.srcIP ^ item.srcPort ^ item.dstIP ^ item.dstPort ^ item.flag; 
hash2 = item.srcIP ^ (123 * item.srcPort) ^ item.dstIP ^ (987 * item.dstPort) ^ (1234567 * item.flag);
```

Where ^ bitwise XOR operation and * multiplication.